# Issue with PyAutoGUI: mouse click not working in subsequent iterations

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I am trying to automate the process of sending emojis as a fun project using PyAutoGUI in Python. My code aims to click on specific coordinates on the screen to select emojis and then press the "Enter" key to send them. However, I encountered an issue when running the code multiple times in a loop.

Problem:
When I set the limit to, for example, 3, and execute the code, the first iteration works perfectly fine, but the subsequent iterations fail to click on the desired coordinates. The mouse moves to the specified coordinates but doesn't perform the click action.

Code:

```py
import pyautogui as pt
import time

pt.FAILSAFE = True
limit = int(input("Number of actions: "))
time.sleep(5)
def send_emoji():
    i = 0
    while i < limit:
        pt.click(x=459, y=699, clicks=1, interval=1, button='left')
        pt.click(x=258, y=460, clicks=1, interval=1, button='left')
        time.sleep(1)
        pt.press('enter')
    
        i += 1
try:
    send_emoji()
except pt.FailSafeException:
    print("Execution stopped due to failsafe (moved mouse to top-left corner).")
```